# What identifies a series in Circonus-IRONdb?

Tags: database, time-series

From docs about [metric name and tags](https://docs.circonus.com/irondb/metric-names-tags-queries/), sereis seems to be identified by a combination of metric name and tags. But in [docs about write api](https://docs.circonus.com/irondb/api/data-submission/), there is nothing refers to tags, and `UUID` plays am important role here while never showed up during the chapter about series name.

So, what really identifies a series, and what is the relationship between `UUID` and metric/tag?